# ios provisioning profile invalid

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile

I have a problem: the provisioning profile for my iOS app is invalid. How can I change this to valid? At the same time, users are using this application. Users should not be affected from this situation. How can I fix it?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Click on the edit button at the bottom of the profile details to edit the provisioning profile. Check all the details are correct on the profile, namely, the appId and certificate are correct and all the devices that the app can be used an are selected (if relevant). Once your sure the details are correct, click generate to renew the profile.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot re-validate an invalid provisioning profile. However, you can regenerate the provisioning profile. Unfortunately, if the provisioning profile is invalid, your users are possibly already experiencing issues. The only way to fix this is to rebuild your application with the regenerated provisioning profile and redistribute your app.

Side Note: Provisioning profiles can often be invalidated prematurely due to distribution certificates being revoked. If you have an app that you've distributed In-House or Ad-Hoc, make sure you keep this in mind to avoid issues like this popping up in the future!

Comment: I clicked Edit and regenerated the certificate. It's now valid. The application is running when I run it. But after a while I am afraid that the application will not work in users.Could there be a situation like not working after a while? Do I need to re-publish to the user?

Comment: If you're running through Xcode, then you're not even using your distribution provisioning profile - you're using a development one. If you're distributing using an Ah-Hoc or In-House provisioned build, then your user are likely to already be experiencing issues and you should redistribute the app. If you're distributing through the App Store then they won't notice anything since Apple resigns and re-provisions all apps before they go into the store.